# Navigation through DrawerLayoutAndroid react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

what I want to do is to navigate to different views through the Drawer layout also it would be great if I could do it in the navBar itself rather than implementing an entirely new toolbar and then adding it to every view[image]

on click on the bar area I am able to activate the drawer but what I want is to use it to navigate to different views.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "onIconClicked" Prop and call a navigator push with it.(http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#content)

Comment: It doesn't work -_- if it did I wouldn't be posting this question it gives some error saying that the function is undefined